# lxml get element names dynamically even for the ones which are nested

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gudid xmlns="http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid gudid.xsd">
<device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid">
  <publicDeviceRecordKey>7c36b446-020c-44ab-9ce7-a85387467e0f</publicDeviceRecordKey>
  <publicVersionStatus>New</publicVersionStatus>
  <deviceRecordStatus>Published</deviceRecordStatus>
  <identifiers>
    <identifier>
      <deviceId>M930756120810</deviceId>
      <deviceIdType>Primary</deviceIdType>
      <deviceIdIssuingAgency>HIBCC</deviceIdIssuingAgency>
      <containsDINumber xsi:nil="true"></containsDINumber>
      <pkgQuantity xsi:nil="true"></pkgQuantity>
      <pkgDiscontinueDate xsi:nil="true"></pkgDiscontinueDate>
      <pkgStatus xsi:nil="true"></pkgStatus>
      <pkgType xsi:nil="true"></pkgType>
    </identifier>
  </identifiers>
  <brandName>Life Instruments</brandName>
  <gmdnTerms>
    <gmdn>
      <gmdnPTName>Orthopaedic knife</gmdnPTName>
      <gmdnPTDefinition>A hand-held manual surgical instrument designed for cutting/shaping bone during an orthopaedic surgical intervention. It is typically a heavy, one-piece instrument with a sharp, single-edged, strong cutting blade at the distal end available in various shapes and sizes, with a handle at the proximal end. It is normally made of high-grade stainless steel. This is a reusable device.</gmdnPTDefinition>
    </gmdn>
  </gmdnTerms>
  <productCodes>
    <fdaProductCode>
      <productCode>LXH</productCode>
      <productCodeName>Orthopedic Manual Surgical Instrument</productCodeName>
    </fdaProductCode>
  </productCodes>
  <deviceSizes/>
  <environmentalConditions/>
</device>
</gudid>
```

I use lxml to parse this xml

```
with open("sample.xml", encoding="utf-8") as f:          
    xml = f.read().encode()                              
                                                         
root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
```

When I tried to loop over the xml I get the following issue

```
for event, element in etree.iterwalk(root, events=("start", "end")):   
    if event == "start":                                               
        print(event, element.tag, element.text)   

                 
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}publicDeviceRecordKey 7c36b446-020c-44ab-9ce7-a85387467e0f
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}publicVersionStatus New
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}deviceRecordStatus Published
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}identifiers None
....
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}device None
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}publicDeviceRecordKey be401033-96bf-46ec-8ac0-b2ce302d2b11
start {http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid}sterilizationMethod Moist Heat or Steam Sterilization
```

Every element seems to have a namespace which I don't want.
I would rather want a flat list from the xml

```
publicDeviceRecordKey                 deviceId             gmdnPtName .....
7c36b446-020c-44ab-9ce7-a85387467e0f  M930756120810        Orthopaedic knife
```

How do i get rid of the namespace in the element.tag please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the tag name without namespace definition, you can get the localname of the element like

```
etree.QName(element).localname
```

You can print the local name and check

```
print(event, etree.QName(element).localname, element.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Kris been struggling since 4 hours with the problem :)